# Не удается установить Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

Появилась необходимость установить Codeception для изучения и дальнейшего применения авто тестов (php). Работаю на Linux mint. Нашел в интернете [иструкцию](https://devacademy.ru/article/tiestirovaniiedah-api-ustanovka-i-ispol-zovaniie-codeception) по которой решил установить

1. Открываю нужную мне папку в терминале и ввожу команду

   composer require "codeception/codeception:*"
2. После установки по мануалы написано:

> Через некоторое время codeception будет скачан. После установки вы сможете использовать его в командной строке. Выполним следующую команду, чтобы проверить, что все установилось корректно:
> "
> 3) Выполняю проверку командой

vendor/bin/codeception --version
Но заходя в папку bin я не нахожу файл codeception, но там есть файл codecept. Скорее всего это то что мне нужно.
4) Ввожу командй `vendor/bin/codecept --version
В ответ получаю

PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/hamster/Desktop/php_test/vendor/codeception/codeception/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hamster/Desktop/php_test/vendor/codeception/codeception/autoload.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/hamster/Desktop/php_test/vendor/codeception/codeception/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/hamster/Desktop/php_test/vendor/codeception/codeception/autoload.php on line 5

`

Comment: Меньше читайте девакадеми всякие. Есть официальный сайт: https://codeception.com/quickstart. Учитесь искать источники информации, которым можно доверять.

Comment: У вас всё установилось без сообщений об ошибках? Потом ничего не делали со своим проектом (перемещали может быть, что-то удаляли)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с чистого листа, из консоли:

```
mkdir codeceptionTest \
&& cd codeceptionTest \
&& composer require "codeception/codeception" --dev \
&& vendor/bin/codecept -V
```

У меня получилось

```
Codeception 4.1.6
```

Думаю, вы упускаете какие-то детали окружения. Типа вы как-то хитро используете виртуалку, или вендор был в гите и вы сделали чекаут после установки, или у вас запущен демон, который удаляет некоторые файлы :-)

Comment: Егор, добрый день! Спасибо за ответ. Но что то не выходит) Именно по последнему запросу && vendor/bin/codecept -V В ответ прилетает выше описанная ошибка.

Comment: @Petr_Anisimov может что-то с композером? Он у вас свежий?

Comment: С ним на сколько я понимаю проблем нет (version 1.10.9). Дело в том, что на mac мне удалось все поставить, проверить версию и тд. Но linux отказывается взаимодейстоввать со мной)

Comment: @Petr_Anisimov а что на линуксе получается в файле `vendor/codeception/codeception/autoload.php`?

Comment: Егор, каким то чудом удалось поставить. Просто все снес и заново сделал. Так и не понял в чем была моя ошибка. Но Вам все равно спасибо за помощь!